# Why haven't I been awarded the bounty for the question by the community?

Tags: support, bounties

Why haven't I been awarded the bounty for *[ASP.NET MVC deployment in a form of distribution package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790184/asp-net-mvc-deployment-in-a-form-of-distribution-package/5988446#5988446)*?

Comment: You will. That's a scheduled job; I think it runs once an hour.

Comment: It says the bounty is ending in 31 minutes..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard it think it says it ended 31 minutes ago..

Comment: @Sevki - right! I never saw such message - guess that's what you see until the scheduled job balpha mentioned is running. :)

Comment: well you have the bounty now.

Comment: @Sathya yipeeee :)

Comment: @Sevki Congrats ;)